# Unificar 2 funciones para leer archivos con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2.x

desde hace un tiempo estoy intentando hacer un simulador de bash usando python, estoy creando los comandos tail y head, para esto cree 2 funciones:

```
def head(textfile):
    content = []
    try:
        file = open(textfile, "r")
        for line in file:
            content.append(line)
    except:
        print("[*] Error: No se ha podido abrir el archivo '{}'".format(textfile))
    else:
        for string in content[:5]:
            print(string)

def tail(textfile):
    content = []
    try:
        file = open(textfile, "r")
        for line in file:
            content.append(line)
    except:
        print("[*] Error: No se ha podido abrir el archivo '{}'".format(textfile))
    else:
        for string in content[len(content) - 5:]:
            print(string)
```

Las 2 funciones son exageradamente parecidas, de hecho solo cambian en un valor:

```
for string in content[len(content) - 5:]:
# aquí el ':' está a la derecha
```

y

```
for string in content[:5]:
# y aquí el ':' está a la izquierda
```

pensé en cambiar ese valor a un parámetro, pero el ':' está puesto en lugares distintos (si no logro explicarme bien lee los comentarios en el código de arriba) me molesta el repetir código así que: ¿qué es lo que puedo hacer para tener una sola función?

Comment: Independientemente de que quieres o no reducir código creo que deberías tener en cuenta la eficiencia de la implementación si se va a usar para archivos grandes, si tienes un archivo de 10 Gb tienes un problema, crear una lista con todas las líneas del fichero cuando solo vas a retornar unas cuantas es muy ineficiente, el proceso ya usa mas de 10 Gb si es que el sistema tiene esa RAM para esto,  además de tardar mucho. Lo que haces es lo que hace `file.readlines` pero más ineficiente aún porque lo haces con un `for` python y `append` en vez de a nivel de C como `readlines`)

Comment: Lo normal es iterar y almacenar en memoria solo las lineas a retornar, en el caso de `head` es muy simple, por ejemplo `lines =  [file.readline() for _ in range(5)]`, en el caso de `tail` se complica porque hay que iterar desde el final e implica jugar con el cursor. Por cierto, SIEMPRE cierra un archivo cuando termines con el o usa el manejador de contexto con `with` para que lo cierre por ti, es muy mala práctica dejar esta tarea al recolector de basura. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de tu auto-respuesta es que para el caso "tail" no funcionará correctamente, ya que en tu segundo ejemplo, lo que ejecutará tu función será en el fondo:

```
for string in content[-5:-1]:
    print(string)
```

y eso no imprimirá la última línea, ya que en un *slice* el elemento final está excluído.

La única forma de poder imprimir los 5 últimos elementos de la lista es usar `content[-5:]`, es decir, omitir el final. Pero ¿cómo lograr eso?

Python tiene la primitiva `slice()` que te permite crear "rodajas" usando una sintaxis alternativa. La desventaja es que no es la sintaxis familiar `[inicio:fin:paso]`, sino `slice(inicio, fin, paso)`. La ventaja es que esta sintaxis puede pasarse como parámetro.

Usando este truco:

```
def headtail(textfile, trozo):
    content = []
    try:
        file = open(textfile, "r")
        for line in file:
            content.append(line)
    except:
        print("[*] Error: No se ha podido abrir el archivo '{}'".format(textfile))
    else:
        for string in content[trozo]:
            print(string)
```

Y lo malo es la invocación, que queda rara. Para head:

```
headtail(file, slice(0,5))
```

Para tail:

```
headtail(file, slice(-5, None))
```

si quieres una sintaxis un poco más amigable, puedes usar [este otro truco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706258/passing-python-slice-syntax-around-to-functions), para generar `slice()` a partir de una sintaxis "entre corchetes":

```
class HazSlice(object):
  def __getitem__(self, item):
    return item

trozo = HazSlice()

# Cabeza
headtail(file, trozo[:5])

# Tail
headtail(file, trozo[-5:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya tengo la solución, iba a borrar la publicación pero dejo la respuesta por si a alguien sirve:
mandas 2 parámetros nuevos la función "minim" y maxim"
quedaría algo así:

```
def headtail(textfile, minim, maxim):
    content = []
    try:
        file = open(textfile, "r")
        for line in file:
            content.append(line)
    except:
        print("[*] Error: No se ha podido abrir el archivo '{}'".format(textfile))
    else:
        for string in content[minim:maxim]:
            print(string)
```

Cuando quieras activar head lo haces de esta manera:

```
headtail(file,0,5)
```

y para tail así:

```
headtail(file,-5,-1)
```